# Is it possible to delete a specific route with route name in the Navigator stack?

Tags: flutter

I have pushNamed 4 pages. I want to know whether the page2 is existing in the stack or not. If page2 exist then when I pushNamed('/page2') it will delete the previous page2 from the stack and create another page2. Thank you.

Example:

```
Navigator stack before:
[page1, page2, page3, page4]

Navigator stack after:
[page1, page3, page4, page2]
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems like an use case of navigator 2.0. Haven't digged too much on it myself but it comes to solve problems like these

Comment: you can also use getx package

Comment: You can use `removeRouteBelow` method. When you push to second page2, check if page2 exist, if it exist, then `Navigator.of(context).removeRouteBelow(page2);`,and push a new page2. Another thing is `UserNavigatorObserver.history`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks everyone I will try to look on getx package.